# Bootcamp High Sierra Upgrade can't boot Windows

Tags: windows-8, boot-camp

Having some confusion regarding which instructions to follow to fix an issue I'm having with my Bootcamp Installation.

I've had a copy of Windows 8 (not 8.1) installed for a quite a long time which worked fine until I upgraded to High Sierra. Is it still listed as a disk in my Startup Assistant.

However when I restart and boot into it, after a minute or so the Mac will attempt to boot but will get a "No Bootable Device" error.

I'm just wary of following any potential wrong instructions which may compromise my data on either my Mac or Windows disk so any help which would show me the best steps would be great.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317791/bootcamp-high-sierra-upgrade-now-not-working

Comment: An accepted answer has been posted at the [other site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317791/bootcamp-high-sierra-upgrade-now-not-working/317829#317829).